# Is it possible to use multiple namespaces for zend model and how will i autoload it?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I am using zend framework for one reporting project which uses two existing databases shared with other applications.

I am connecting to these database using zend multi db.

My question is, Is it possible to use multiple namespace for the models. Because both my databases contain tables with same name. Or what is the best practice for dealing with this kind of scenario.

Can i try something like,

```
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
                                            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
                                            'namespace' => '',
                                            'resourceTypes' => array(
                                                'form' => array(
                                                    'path' => 'forms/',
                                                    'namespace' => 'Form_',
                                                    ),
                                                'DBFIRST' => array(
                                                    'path' => 'models/',
                                                    'namespace' => 'Model_'
                                                    ),
            'DBSECOND' => array(
                                                    'path' => 'models/',
                                                    'namespace' => 'Model_'
                                                    )
                                            ),
                                        ));
```

Can someone tell me what is the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet in this situation would be to add each namespace to the `application.ini`

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = DBFIRST_
autoloaderNamespaces[] = DBSECOND_
```

then you can add any file you need to the library using a similar structure to the application.

```
/library
    /DBFIRST
        /model
            Table.php //class DBFIRST_Model_Table etc.
    /DBSECOND
        /model
        /form
```

I'm sure it can be done the way you are suggesting, I'm just not sure it's worth the trouble. Since the only classes that you will really need to be careful with are the DbTable classes, because these will need to rely on a specific db adapter. Your actual models or services shouldn't care which adapter is talking to the database or even that a database exists.